# Laravel Eloquent complex join statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My database structure is the following:

[image: Relation blogger <-> Topics]

So I've got a **Bloggers table** (sorry for the typo in the image), which has **3 topic fields**, all 3 are **foreign keys** to the **topics' table id**.

I made a Blogger view front-end with a simple table showing all blogger columns. At the moment, the id's of the topics are being shown instead of the names though.

How can I change this?
I've already tried the following in my Controller, but that just creates duplicates in the view with different values in the `main_topic` column.

```
$bloggers= DB::table('bloggers')
            ->join('topics', function ($join) {
                $join
                    ->on('bloggers.main_topic', '=', 'topics.id')
                    ->orOn('bloggers.subtopic1', '=', 'topics.id')
                    ->orOn('bloggers.subtopic2', '=', 'topics.id');
            })
            ->select('bloggers.*', 'topics.name as main_topic')
            ->get();

return view('pages.bloggers', compact('bloggers'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my specific question was a little different from the answers given, so I'll post it here in case anyone needs it in the future.

So I've got 3 tables: **bloggers**, **topics** and a pivot table called **blogger_topic**. **bloggers** contains 3 foreign keys (integers) to topics called **main_topic**, **subtopic1**, **subtopic2**. The pivot table contains a **blogger_id**, and a **topic_id**.

What I ended up with:

**Blogger.php model:**

```
public function mainTopic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Topic', 'main_topic', 'id');
}
public function subtopicOne()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Topic', 'subtopic1', 'id');
}
public function subtopicTwo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Topic', 'subtopic2', 'id');
}
```

**Topic.php model:**

```
public function bloggers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Blogger');
}
```

**View (blogger.blade.php):**

```
@foreach($bloggers as $blogger)
    {{ $blogger->mainTopic }}
    {{ $blogger->subtopicOne }}
    {{ $blogger->subtopicTwo }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your database tables if possible as below (sample link), by creating a pivot table. And then I think you should make relationships in Blogger and Topic model files with many-to-many. Then it would be very easy to fetch all related topics. For eg,

```
$topics = $blogger->topics;
```

[Here you can reference the sample db table designs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGTSf.png)

I kindly recommend you to use models in Laravel coz they'll make your life more simple. Hope this help.

Comment: I'm trying to use models, though I'm not _that_ familiar yet with Laravel so I'm just following the documentation on that. Fetching the topics like you suggested is not working, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you cant change your database, you could use group_concat on the results. Not sure if it will work but something like:

```
DB::table('bloggers')
            ->join('topics', function ($join) {
                $join
                    ->on('bloggers.main_topic', '=', 'topics.id')
                    ->orOn('bloggers.subtopic1', '=', 'topics.id')
                    ->orOn('bloggers.subtopic2', '=', 'topics.id');
            })
            ->groupby('bloggers.id')
            ->select('bloggers.*', 'topics.name as main_topic', DB::raw('group_concat(topics.name)'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: I changed my database to contain the pivot table for bloggers and topics. Also, the group concat isn't really what I was looking for, since I'm just trying to map the 3 columns from the Bloggers table (`main_topic`, `subtopic1`, `subtopic2`) with their respective names.

Comment: If you have the pivot table you can then create a many to many eloquent relationship between bloggers and topics. 

In the blogger model put this:
`public function topics() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Topic', 'pivot_table_name');
}`

And in the Topic model put this:
`public function bloggers() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blogger', 'pivot_table_name');
}`

Your pivot table should contain the following:
`blogger_id`
`topic_id`

You can remove the topic columns from the blogger model. You can then reference the topics by `$blog->topics()`;

Comment: Did all the things you said, but I can't seem to figure out where to do the `$blogger->topics()` statement. Do I do this in my Controller, blade (HTML),...?

Comment: You can use it in the blade. To find a specific topic you can pass an  id to the it. `@foreach($blogger->topics as $topic){ {{$topic->name}} } @endforeach` will print the name of every topic a blogger has. `{{$blogger->topics->find(1)->name}}` will print the name of the topic with an id of 1.